# My regex always returns true

Tags: regex

Well, I have following requirements:

> 1. Minimum 8 characters
> 2. Contains at least one upper case letter
> 3. Contains at least one lower case letter

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]){8,}$
```

But it always returns true even though the requirement is not fulfilled. May anyone advise what is wrong?

Comment: which language is this regex use for?

Comment: javascript @SamuelToh .. is it matter by the way?

Comment: Probably write a few if-else statements to verify this? Much easier and you can also highlight to the end user what is wrong with the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `.` before the quantifier.

`/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8}/` should do the job.

**Example:**

```js
var check = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8}$/

var correctInput = "abcdefgH";
var incorrectInput = "agH";

if (check.exec(correctInput)) {
    console.log("correct input: pass");
}

if (!check.exec(incorrectInput)) {
    console.log("incorrect input: pass");
}
```

While the suggested regular expression works and they look fancy but I am against it, especially in this context.

In terms of code readability and maintainability,  I think your code will look better by having a few `if-else` statements to check for the conditions. Another advantage of such coding style is that you can produce hint messages to tell the end-users what went wrong. Instead of a generic error message.

Comment: `g` option is not needed. Note that your regex starts with `^` and ends with `$`, so you want to match the **whole** text, so there is no way to have multiple matches.